# Find folder by date criteria deep in file structure

Tags: powershell, replace, find

Folder structure:

```
\\server\DropFolder.
├───PRD
│   ├───CTASales
│   │   └───v1.7
│   │           setup.bat
│   │
│   ├───CTASalesDeleteItems
│   │   └───v1.1
│   │           setup.bat
│   │
│   └───Feature1
│       └───v1.3.1
│               setup.bat
│
└───STG
    ├───CTASales
    │   ├───v1.7
    │   │       setup.bat
    │   │
    │   └───v1.8.1
    │           setup.bat
    │
    ├───CTASalesDeleteItems
    │   └───v1.1
    │           setup.bat
    │
    └───Feature1
        └───2.7
                setup.bat
```

If the version folder `vx.x.x` was created within 12 hours, I need to execute my code to do a custom find and replace on the `setup.bat` file.  Do I need a `foreach` loop to get into `PRD/STG` then another one to look into each `CTA` folder to look at the version creation times?

Code so far:

```
Clear-Host
$Radsdrop = '\\SERVER\DROPFOLDER'
$date = Get-Date
$hours = '-9999999'

foreach ($env in (Get-ChildItem $RadsDrop -Directory))
{ 
   if($env.Name -eq 'STG')
   {    
     Get-ChildItem $Radsdrop -Recurse -Filter 'setup.bat' | 
       Where-Object {$_.Parent.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours($hours)} | 
       Get-Content -Filter 'setup.bat' |
       ForEach-Object
      { 
        $_ -replace 'dev', 'stg' `
      } | Set-Content c:\setup.bat
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how I need to get the contents of the bat file and set it back to appropriate folders.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to get all `setup.bat` and then use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter all parent directories older then 12 hours:

```
Get-ChildItem '\\server\DropFolder' -Recurse -Filter 'setup.bat' | 
    Where-Object {$_.Parent.CreationTime -le (Get-Date).AddHours(12)} |
    ForEach-Object {
        # do your find and replace with $_
    }
```

---

Edit to your comment:

```
Get-ChildItem '\\server\DropFolder' -Recurse -Filter 'setup.bat' | 
    Where-Object {$_.Parent.CreationTime -le (Get-Date).AddHours(12)} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $content = Get-Content $_            
        if ($_.Parent.BaseName -eq 'STG')
        {            
            $content = $content -replace 'dev', 'stg'   
        }
        elseif ($_.Parent.BaseName -eq 'PRD')
        {
            $content = $content -replace 'prd', '' 
        }    
        $content | Set-Content $_
    }
```

Comment: Nice, nice, nice : ). I've always wondered if `$_.Parent` gave you the full (parent) `FSO` ?

Comment: @sodawillow Thank you. `$_.Parent` is the first parent as `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`. Or what you mean with `FSO`?

Comment: "file system object" - you answered my question :).

Comment: @MartinBrandl thank you for your response. This is a neat approach.  My only confusion is, what do I need to do after in my Set-Content portion? Still messing with it, so I may come up with something soon...

Comment: You mean what you need to pass to it? If you show us your script im sure we can help you, just edit your question.

Comment: @MartinBrandl Updated. Thank you!

Comment: @MartinBrandl just saw your code. It looks perfect and way more simple than what I had.. But for some reason it doesn't get past the `Where-Object` portion.  Still messing with it.

Comment: upps, probably you have to write `.AddHours(-12)`

Comment: @MartinBrandl well I had already changed that. It looks like `Parent.CreationTime` doesn't return anything.

Comment: hm, you can check the output by using `Get-ChildItem '\\server\DropFolder' -Recurse -Filter 'setup.bat' | foreach { $_.Parent | fl * -Force }`